# How can add sql line end of laravel migration schema::create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

AppServiceProvider

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Blueprint::macro('partitionByRange', function ($column) {
            return // 'partition by range ({$column})';
        });
    }
```

Migration file

```
        Schema::create('accounting_plan_connections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->morphs('accounting_plan_connectable');
            $table->bigInteger('accounting_plan_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('expense_center_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->partitionByRange("created_at");
        });
```

Actually I am trying this native query to implement laravel migration:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (

...col definitions

) PARTITION BY RANGE (created_at);
```

Comment: Then what is the purpose of using ***laravel migration***?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam is right migration is simple your code and reduce to write raw query

Comment: Specify that you need to **insert data** into it or, as you mentioned, **create a table.**?

Comment: @Deniz Gölbaş please share

Comment: Using migration makes development and deploy easier. It also has a lot of other job-facilitating features. Anyway, that's not the point. It is not possible to assign a partition afterwards in PostgreSql. We need to make this assignment while creating the table. I cannot update the table by converting an alter table query with a raw query afterwards. In addition there are 80+ tables available. I don't want to convert them all to raw sql. Let me update my question: how do I add a raw partition when creating a table in migrations. Please do not offer packages. @AbdullaNilam